# Columns of type integer cannot hold values of type char

Tags: java

I have a table named `BENEFICTOR` in my database. When I try to insert into this table it gives me the following error:

> columns of type integer cannot hold values of type char and i am typing a true values in the textfields (T1,T2,...).

```
private void Add_PeopleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int bid=Integer.parseInt(T1.getText());
    int fid=Integer.parseInt(T2.getText());
    int idnum=Integer.parseInt(T5.getText());
    int age = Integer.parseInt(T14.getText());
    try{
        String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/spc";
        String username="issam";
        String password="issam";
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        String Query="INSERT INTO BENEFICTOR (BID,FID,FULL_NAME,GENDER,AGE,IDNUM,STATUS,ORIGINAL_AREA,RECENT_AREA,EVAL,PHONE_NUMBER1,PHONE_NUMBER2,SITUATION,VISIT) VALUES ("+bid+" , "+fid+" , '"+T3.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T4.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , "+age+" , "+idnum+" , '"+T6.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , '"+T7.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T8.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T9.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , '"+T10.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T11.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T12.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T13.getText().toString()+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(Query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"A Person Added To Database");
        T1.setText(null);
        T2.setText(null);
        T3.setText(null);
        T4.setSelectedItem(0);
        T5.setText(null);
        T6.setSelectedItem(0);
        T7.setText(null);
        T8.setText(null);
        T9.setSelectedItem(0);
        T10.setText(null);
        T11.setText(null);
        T12.setSelected(true);
        T13.setSelected(true);
        T14.setText(null);

    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how can i fix this ? thank you.

Here Is the Types of columns fields:

```
BID:INTEGER,FID:INTEGER,FULL_NAME:VARCHAR,GENDER:VARCHAR,AGE:INTEGER,IDNUM:INTEGER,STATUS:VARCHAR,ORIFINAL_AREA:VARCHAR,RECENT_AREA:VARCHAR,EVAL:VARCHAR,PHONE_NUMBER1:INTEGER,PHONE_NUMBER2:INTEGER,SITUATION:VARCHAR,VISIT:VARCHAR
```

The `Status`, `Gendre`, `eval` are all ComboBoxes. `visit` and `Situation` are checkBoxes

Comment: Can you share the Benefictor table model? Also can you try using PreparedStatement and setInt functions to add the parameters? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Please check the type of column that is you insert data by calling .toString().I mean is that you insert data just like T6.getSelectedItem().toString() in Status column.Please check type of Status is really char type or not.Please check type of other columns that u insert data with .toString().

Comment: You're asking people to play a guessing game here. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to store `char` values in a variable of type `java.lang.Integer` you need to parse them like `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c))` where c is your `char` value. 
Or you could change your variable type to `Object` then you use the wrapper types  `java.lang.Integer`and `java.lang.Character` to store your data

Comment: I am parsing them like Integer.parseInt .. in my code where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the colums PHONE_NUMBER1 and PHONE_NUMBER2 are of type int and you are trying to insert a string into them.
Try to parse the phonenumbers the way you parsed the other int values:

```
int phoneNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(T10.getText());
int phoneNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(T11.getText());
```

Your query should then look like this:

```
String Query="INSERT INTO BENEFICTOR (BID,FID,FULL_NAME,GENDER,AGE,IDNUM,STATUS,ORIGINAL_AREA,RECENT_AREA,EVAL,PHONE_NUMBER1,PHONE_NUMBER2,SITUATION,VISIT) VALUES ("+bid+" , "+fid+" , '"+T3.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T4.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , "+age+" , "+idnum+" , '"+T6.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , '"+T7.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T8.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T9.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , "+phoneNumber1+" , "+phoneNumber2+" , '"+T12.getText().toString()+"' , '"+T13.getText().toString()+"')";
```

Comment: I fixed it and it still the same problem

Comment: Looking at your description this should solve it, since PHONE_NUMBER1 and PHONE_NUMBER2 are indeed of type integer. Could you update the code in your question?